# Enable an Button in MFC Dialog

Tags: mfc

I have two buttons:

1. Radio button: "Hex"
2. Button: "A"

I want to enable "A" anytime users "Hex" button is checked (the state of "A" is "Disabled" when it is created), how can I do that? Thank everyone.

[image: The Calculator MFC Application]

Answer (score 10):

You need to use [`CButton`'s `EnableWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kbfsahf.aspx) function.

```
buttonA.EnableWindow( TRUE );
```

If you do not have the `CButton` object, you can access the button by calling `GetDlgItem` with its ID:

```
GetDlgItem( IDC_BUTTON_A )->EnableWindow( TRUE );
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's `buttonA.EnableWindow(TRUE)` or simply `buttonA.EnableWindow()`.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yeah fair point, though "true" will work just as well, with a warning :)

Comment: But I didn't have any CButton object which handle buttonA. Can you show me the function to handle it please? Thank you very much.

Comment: You must either get the window handle of the button and send it the WM_ENABLE message, or use the class wizard to create a CButton object with the buttons you want to be able to control.

Comment: @Jeff: [`WM_ENABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632621.aspx) is sent **by the system** when an application changes the enabled state of a window. It is not one of the messages that an application is supposed to generate.

Comment: @PhùngKhánhHiên If you don't have a CButton you can use GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON)->EnableWindow(TRUE);

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` mechanism to enable/disable the 'A' or any other button in your dialog. By default it is not available for dialog based application but you can easily enable them by following this [article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/commandui/article.php/c1911/Using-ONUPDATECOMMANDUI-with-controls.htm).

The code in your update function will look something like this:

```
void CCalculatorDlg::OnUpdateButtonA(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
        if( m_ctrlBtnHex.GetCheck() == BST_CHECKED )
        {
            pCmdUI->Enable( TRUE );
        }
        else
        {
            pCmdUI->Enable( FALSE );
        }
}
```

In your case since A, B, C, D, E, F will essentially have same states so you can instead do this:

```
void CCalculatorDlg::OnUpdateButtonA(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
        if( m_ctrlBtnHex.GetCheck() == BST_CHECKED) )
        {
            m_ctrlBtnA.EnableWindow( TRUE );
            m_ctrlBtnB.EnableWindow( TRUE );
            m_ctrlBtnC.EnableWindow( TRUE );
            // so on...
        }
        else
        {
            m_ctrlBtnA.EnableWindow( FALSE );
            m_ctrlBtnB.EnableWindow( FALSE );
            m_ctrlBtnC.EnableWindow( FALSE );
            // so on...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NameOfYourButton.EnableWindow( TRUE );
```